# EmguCV 3.0.0 - CvInvoke.cvConvert equivalent

Tags: emgucv

I want to convert between Matrix and Image in EmguCV 3.0.0.

I saw in this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DfTS5a9xmwo) that you can do this with the CvInvoke.cvConvert method. But it seems this method doesn't exist anymore in EmguCV 3.0.0. I did find the method CVInvoke.ConvertMaps , but this method requires two input and two output arrays. Is this method equivalent if I use empty arrays as the second arrays?

Answer (score 0):

Try the (.ToImage) method. It operates to convert to a Matrix to an image. a working example in C# is:

```
Image<Bgr,Byte> img1 = imgMat.ToImage<Bgr, Byte>();
```

You can also change it to a grayscale by using (gray,byte)

You can also find an example in VB at (http://www.emgu.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5209).